# Losing my Emoji, probably in UTF8String

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm doing this type of thing:

```
const char *cstring = [textIn UTF8String];
```

and then later I do this:

```
CGContextShowText(ctx, cstring, strlen(cstring));
```

I'm losing my Emoji in the process, though the font selected with `CGContextSelectFont` supports them. Is there an easy workaround?

Comment: feel free to retag if this is not, in fact, CoreText.

Comment: The emoji is *not* at the end of the string, is it?

Comment: This is not, in fact, CoreText.

Comment: Are you sure your font supports emoji? Typically emoji is satisfied by the Apple Color Emoji font, and is rendered through the use of font fallback. But CoreGraphics's text rendering mechanism does not support font fallback.

Comment: @KevinBallard yes I use `UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:` elsewhere in my app with some size problems with Emoji, but it generally works. But I'm normally using normal `UIKit` stuff like `UILabel`

Comment: @Yar: That's meaningless. Most font rendering mechanisms, including WebKit and CoreText (which power UILabel), support font fallbacks, which means it will fall back to the Apple Color Emoji font for emoji when the current font doesn't have the glyph. But CoreGraphics doesn't do this.

Comment: Also, you are *not* using `CGContextSelectFont`, are you?

Comment: @Yar Post the code that creates and sets the font on `ctx`.  Also post an example string that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @robmayoff I'm selecting the font with `CGContextSelectFont(ctx, font.fontName.UTF8String, fontSize, kCGEncodingMacRoman);` (hmmm that encoding looks suspicious) and I cannot post an example string because I put them in with text boxes elsewhere. Though I'll get you some ASCII codes right now.

Comment: @Yar: MacRoman doesn't support emoji. And your string isn't in MacRoman at all.

Comment: @Yar: You may want to switch over to CoreText for font rendering. CoreGraphics's support is rather primitive, and I don't see any way to control the encoding aside from "MacRoman vs font-specific"

Comment: "I'm selecting the font with `CGContextSelectFont`..." That's the problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/275447/335858).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unicode Character Not Showing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275437/unicode-character-not-showing)

Comment: Fascinating @dasblinkenlight I'll check out that answer and see. So if I switch to drawInRect:withFont:, is that CoreText? Thanks!

Comment: @Yar: UIKit string drawing is actually powered by WebKit, but that's kind of irrelevant. `-drawInRect:withFont:` or the other variants should work just fine.